# Running ChromeDriver or FirefoxDriver on Selenium without it's GUI (headless mode)

Tags: java, selenium

**JAVA (selenium code snippet):**

```
    manageDriver();
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(url);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3+r, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This is enough to create a ChromeDriver window, which is very annoying for my clients. Is there a way I can make ChromeDriver run without the GUI?

EDIT:
I have seen something called xvfb, not sure what it is. Could I use it to make my firefoxDriver or chromeDriver headless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a X server. Follow these steps:
Install xvfb:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Then run it with a display number. For ex 40:

```
Xvfb :40 &
```

Run client:

```
Xvfb :40 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -extension RANDR &
```

Export Display:

```
export DISPLAY=:40
```

Start run your scripts